What does さっぱり mean by itself?

「お住まいは？」
「神奈川です」 …自分は何を正直に。
「やっぱり……」
何がやっぱりかさっぱりだ。
「七夕と言えば平塚ですから」

This is a back and fort between two characters. The first character is asking things about the second one, and the second one seems to answer with some reluctance.
As far I understand the dialog is such:

"Where do you live?"
"Kanagawa" Why am I being so honest?
"As I thought."

But when what is he trying to say exactly? What nuance does さっぱり here have? I would have thought "I don't understand maybe" but it's used all by itself.

さっぱり(だ) used on its own usually means either of:

さっぱり分からない = I have no idea / I don't understand at all
さっぱり上手くいかない = It's not going well at all / It's terrible

In this context, it's "I have no idea".

何がやっぱりかさっぱりだ。

I have no idea what he/she means by "I knew it".
"As I thought"? Why?


